# LUKS Password or auto login file?

Tags: password, luks

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Hi, just bought a new laptop and have forgotten the LUKS password for 2 USB-128GB drive backups.

On the old laptop I have it set to auto-login to the LUKS drives on start-up and still works fine. I don't really need that actual password, but it would be handy. I am hoping I find whatever file the old one is using to auto-login and transfer that file to the new laptop.

I checked the LUKS drives and only slot-0 is being used on both. I thought I might be able to add another password since it is already accessible, but it asks for the current password. Catch-22.

The backups are about 80GB, so copying off is an option, just not a pleasant one.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: If it is not really necessary to have the backup encrypted, this is a good time to copy your backup into a regular file system (without encryption). Please spend some time thinking about it before deciding which way to go.

Comment: @user535733 Why is it so hard to get a straight answer? You assume way too much. I stated that the backup drives are USB, as in, plugged in when I need to do a backup. My Home Folder is encrypted with a password so that thief is welcome to the laptop. Well, not welcome but I am comfortable with that unlikely eventuality. Now, does anyone have some help for me?

Comment: @sudodus Hmmm, let me see, unencrypted backup data on removable, pocket-sized media. Yup, safe as houses. Back to my original question.

Comment: I don't use LUKS, but I believe it should be possible to obtain the master key from an *open* volume using `dmsetup table --showkeys`. See if google can fill in the rest.

Comment: It is more difficult to recover data from an encrypted backup, but sometimes it is necessary with encryption. I am no expert on LUKS encryption, but I know that there are such experts. Let us hope that one of them will see your question and give you the answer you want. Otherwise, my solution would be to have the backup data unencrypted for a while and then encrypt them again in the new system (of your new laptop).

Answer (score 0):

## Seahorse

Seahorse is the passwordmanager used by default. Can you find your passwort there?

Comment: Thanks I will go searching. Much appreciated.